# Normal map baking does not reflect details

Tags: normals

I have unwrapped the hi poly model:

[image]

And I have unwrapped the lo poly model:

[image]

Then I select the hi poly and the lo poly and bake the normal map.
However, there are no details in the normal map:

[image]

Does anybody see any obvious mistakes I might have made?

Thank you very much for the help!

Here is a close-up of the difference between the hi and lo poly model:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any major difference from the hi-res to the low res as far as normals. I don't think there is really anything to bake.

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ I have added a close-up to show the difference between hi and lo poly model. Do you still think there is nothing to bake?

Comment: The *Selected To Active* checkbox isn't checked in your screenshots. Was it activated while baking ?

Comment: @MrZak Ah, you are my hero! Thank you. That was the problem!

Comment: Can you make your comment the answer?

Comment: I had a similar issue, and found that changing to cycles render worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When baking a normal map from highpoly mesh to lowpoly, several conditions have to be taken into account (assuming lowpoly is already unwrapped):

1. Highpoly must be selected first, lowpoly - last. So [lowpoly should be active, i.e. selected last](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21047/which-object-should-be-selected-when-selected-to-active-is-check-for-texture-bak). Also they have to be in the same place in 3D space.
2. Lowpoly must have image to be baked to. If Blender Internal, It's simply a matter of assigning image in UV/Image Editor while mesh in Edit mode (or by using a material). If Cycles, Image node with this image should be selected in Node Editor.
3. In [Render Bake](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/bake.html) settings, *Selected To Active* has to be checked.

   [image]

   This will make Blender to bake the normals from the secondary selection to the primary selection in 3D Viewport.

---

Also read:

- [Baking normal maps from highpoly to lowpoly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14975/baking-normals-from-high-to-low-poly-mesh-for-game-object)
- [Bake normal maps](http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/bake-normal-maps.php)
- [Baking Normal maps in Blender Internal](http://thezedlab.com/quick-reference-baking-normals-from-a-bump-map/) | [Baking Normal maps in Cycles](http://thezedlab.com/quick-reference-using-normal-maps-in-bi-and-cycles/)