# Bake a Displacement map from a cylinder object

Tags: modeling, displacement

I have this twisted rope created from a bezier circle with modifiers. To reduce the overal poly count I want use discplacement map for this. So my question is how can I bake a displacement map of this object so I can apply it to a simple cylinder?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). A *displacement* map probably won't help with polycount that much. But a *normal map* could work really well in this case.

Comment: Hi Jachym, I'm probably going to use these objects in another renderer and for that reason I'd really like to learn how to make a displacement map out of this.

Comment: Search for highpoly to lowpoly like here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/88700/2214

Answer (score 3):

Since you're baking scalar displacement from a cylinder, the set-up isn't too bad.. the illustration below shows the rope shaded with its height-map-to-cylinder.

[image]

Assuming your rope has its object Z axis straight up its core, with this tree, you put the radial distance from its surface to an (imaginary) cylinder, in this case with radius of 0.65, straight into the strength of a pure-white emission shader.

Put the UV unwrapped low-poly cylinder in the same location as the rope, at the world origin, and bake the emission from selected (the rope), to active (the cylinder) Bake into a floating-point format, 16 bits will probably do.

Then the baked map can drive a Displacement shader for the cylinder:

[image]

The cylinder, displaced, is on the left, next to its baked height-map, and the original rope on the right.

It *is* possible to bake Vector Displacement .. it gets a bit more complicated, with an intermediate map of World-Space positions baked for the Hi-res object, from which positions of the Lo-res object are then subtracted, and baked again, into an exactly corresponding UV map.

Comment: .. although, as you can see, in this particular case, a procedural wave texture would do the job without baking an image.

Comment: Hi Robin, what node did you use for Length node? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: It's one of the options in the _Converter > Vector Math_ node, sorry, I should always remember to clarify that. I will edit, once you've got it working, if you try it, and nothing else has come up, that's not clear enough.

Comment: Thanks!. I've added the nodes and had to increase the substract value to make the black/white colors visible. But for some reason the top and the bottom of the twisted object now has a white glow.

Comment: The projection is radial, the caps should just follow along, without any displacement of their own.. I wouldn't bake those.. or make sure they are pitch black. But there _will_ be a problem for the renderer, generating the geometry to go over the sharp corner.. there would be with any map. If you don't mind a bevel to the caps, or rounded ends, model them in before the bake, that might give the renderer a hand.

Comment: I think I didn't explain it well. Here is an image which shows the problem with the glow at the beginning and end of the high poly mesh. -> https://i.imgur.com/JLM25gh.png

Comment: I _think_ that's the sudden interpolation of normals between horizontal and vertical, a smooth-shading artefact... (my ropes don't have ends, so np). afk atm,  you've got to introduce some kind of bevel.. smoothly reduce radius / profile top and bottom. Or, what does splitting normals (Autosmooth) do to it, if anything?

Answer (score 2):

### Highpoly to Lowpoly

- Add Cylinder (lowpoly) at the same place as rope (highpoly) and *Unwrapp* *Cylinder*
- Add material - the only one thing that matters is add *Texture* node (New) and keep this **node selected**
- Under *Bake* choose *Bake Type* and enable **Selected to Active**
- Select highpoly (rope) than lowpoly (cylinder) with Shift
- *Bake*

### Bake Normal

With Cycles you can bake Normals (not Displacement)

[image]

### Bake Displacement

To bake Displacement you would have to download 2.79 and use *Blender Internal* (BI) engine that has this feature. To let Blender know what Image texture to use - switch lowpoly to edit mode, select all vertices, go to UV/Image editor and press New (to generate image). Blender bakes into image actually used in this editor.

[image]